# Boosting boolean fields in Solr

Tags: sorting, solr

Is it possible to boost boolean fields in Solr so that they receive a higher score?

We've got an index which looks a bit like this:

- document_id
- title
- description
- keywords
- is_reviewed

When searching, documents that have been reviewed (ie. is_reviewed = true) should be weighted more heavily than those that haven't, rather than exclude them completely.

Using `is_review:true^100` doesn't seem to work, and excludes unreviewed items instead of just giving them a lower weighting.  If there a different way this can be achieved?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some query parsers have a feature dedicated to this kind of usage. For example, the dismax query parser has a [boost query `bq`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29) which allows you to boost documents which match a query by adding its clauses to the original query. There is also a [boost function `bf`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29) which allows you to multiply scores by the result of a function. For example, using `is_review` as this `bf` parameter,

- the score of every document whose `is_review` field is undefined will be multiplied by 0.
- the score of every document so that `is_review`=`false` will be multiplied by one.
- the score of every documentso that `is_review`=`true` will be multiplied by two.

`is_review:true^100` shouldn't exclude non reviewed items unless you are using `AND` as the [default query operator](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator). In this case, you could try to replace `is_review:true^100` by `(is_review:true^100 OR is_review:false^0)`.

If you are interested in the boost feature of the dismax query parser but would like to stick to the default query parser, you can use the [boost query parser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/BoostQParserPlugin.html) which will allow you to multiply the scores of any query with any function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not using the dismax handler with this query in particular as it builds up the search using a range of fields and I ended up getting some strange behavior, but I'll check out the boost function or use the second method, both which looks like they can solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but I haven't been able to get this working.  My test query looks like this: deftype=dismax&q=test&bq=is_reviewed:true^100000, which I assumed would boost documents with the is_reviewed field set to true high up the list, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  The is_reviewed field is defined as a standard boolean field in my schema config. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: You should add debugQuery=true to your query parameters to see how your query is parsed and how scores are computed. If you manage to paste your Solr response somewhere, I could give a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adrien.  I've enabled the debug query option, but from what I can see, the boolean field looks like it might just be ignored as it's not mentioned anywhere in the query explanation.  Do you mind if I send you an email with the info?

Comment: Actually, I think it may be working after all... Might be something else interfering with the scoring.

Comment: Feel free to send me an email if you want.

Answer (score 4):

## Drupal

Here is the solution for those who're using Drupal CMS.

First, find your field name in Schema Browser at /solr/admin/schema.jsp

Then, depending on the module which you use, try the following examples:

#### Apachesolr module

Code example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_apachesolr_query_alter().
 */
function hook_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  $query->addParam('bq', array('is_review' =>
    '(is_review:true^100 OR is_review:false^0)'
  ));
}
```

#### Search Solr API module

Code example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_solr_query_alter().
 */
function hook_search_api_solr_query_alter(&$call_args, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  $call_args['params']['bq'][] = '(is_review:true^100 OR is_review:false^0)';
}
```